# zend framework routing with "/"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I have an encrypted parameter in ZF2 routing that has "/" in it for e.g:

```
http://domain.com/request/$2y$14$OmovR9wA1TnBG2fxdKuU9ORYTPGChgfyesGVxilP74**/**2F2t8eJgbNF2
```

On submit of this request the URL turns to

```
http://domain.com/request/$2y$14$OmovR9wA1TnBG2fxdKuU9ORYTPGChgfyesGVxilP74**%**2F2t8eJgbNF2
```

this causes a problem an apache server throws an error saying page not found. Is there a way from where i can stop converting the "/" to "%" in the parameter field. My .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

EDIT

Route code:

```
 'exampleroute' => array(
    'type'    => 'segment',
    'options' => array(

            'route'    => '/exampleroute/[:regexparameter]',
            'constraints' => array(

                     'regexparameter' => '[$.a-zA-z0-9_-]*',

            ),
            'defaults' => array(

                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Mynamespace\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'exampleroute',
                    'action'        => 'example',
            ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add "%2F" => "/" in  Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment File in ZF2 library. Now its working fine

Comment: Do i understand you correctly that you changed the core-files? There should be another way, I'm sure your route-configuration just needed a little tuning ;)

Comment: I saw an article on zend's bug page that it was a problem in zf 1. I simply applied it in zf 2 as well. Is anything wrong with that ?

Comment: I won't just say "yes", because it heavily depends on implementation... As i said, i think your route-configuration is all that needs to be touched ;)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions in regards to route configuration ?

Comment: Well, if you would ADD your route config, i would maybe be able to ^^